# Independent Artists Vs Signed artists with masters ownership

Tags: live-music, music-business

I would like to know at the end of the day what is the importance of being signed and of being **independent** as a music artist?

Lets say you are signed but you have an **ownership for your masters**, how does that makes you different that the artist that is independent when it comes to getting money for your music?

To what extent does having the ownership helps and artist, what sort of things you can do with those masters?

Thanks